# Vb: how to pause a loop for a certain amount of time and then continue?

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim d As Integer
    For d = 0 To TextBox2.Text

        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)

       //a code that pauses the loop but does not stop the browser thread

    Next d
```

Comment: If some code pauses the loop than it will pause the thread.  What are you trying to do here anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the browser is rendering on a separate thread.  If it is then the following should work:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) ' Sleep for 3 seconds
```

If the browser control *is* rendering on the same thread as your application then you will have to refactor the code to utilize a timer as Thomas L suggested.