# How can I pause a Visual Basic loop and then continue?

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vb: how to pause a loop for a certain amount of time and then continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137638/vb-how-to-pause-a-loop-for-a-certain-amount-of-time-and-then-continue)

I'm trying to make a Youtube View hack. Since YouTube record a view after you watch the video for 5 seconds, I want to pause the refreshing loop. Here it is so far:

```
Dim d As Integer
    For d = 0 To 50
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("Youtube.com")
        //pause here
    Next d
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I've formatted your code for you (the first one's free). Why's this question tagged with C++?

Comment: try to explain in better detail - why 50 interations?  what do you mean by "pause the refreshing loop"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim d As Integer
For d = 0 To 50
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("Youtube.com") 'Navigate to Youtube.
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) '"Pause" for 5 seconds.
Next d
```

You might also want to review the documentation at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx).